# Can't login to Magento admin 1.9 timezone (Etc/UTC)

Tags: magento-1.9, backend

When I went to login to my magento backend today I started getting an exception of timezone (Etc/UTC) is not a known timezone.

Comment: This is most likely an issue with your PHP version

Answer (score 1):

I have had this issue couple of hours ago as well, my fix around this was to go to:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Reports/Model/Resource/Order/Collection.php
```

Then go to line 373 and 374, and replace Etc/UTC to UTC.
This was my fix for now, let's see if there are others. :)

Edit: Courtesy to simonthesorcerer upgrading the PHP to 5.4 has fixed the issue as well! 
I would recommend doing that instead. Make sure you rename the php.ini file in the public_html directory to php5.ini, well in my case I had to.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php you should not use Etc/UTC as a timezone and UTC should be used so your fix to the source was correct.

I've also had this error running PHP 5.4.44 so just upgrading to PHP 5.4 may not be the right fix.